# MySQL process running for long time, slowed server to crawl, how to debug

Tags: mysql, linux

A system I work on was down to an absolute crawl this morning.

I ran ps -eh to see if I could find anything, and there was a mysql process that had been running for over 46 minutes.

I restarted MySQL and everything sped right back up, running just like normal.

Now I'm keeping an eye on the open processes and I see that MySQL is once again creeping up in time...every time I refresh a few more seconds are added to it, eg an hour ago it said it had been running for 19 seconds, and every few minutes I refresh and there's another second...now it's up to about 50 seconds. It has been consistently a second or two higher every time I run ps -eh.

I ran mysql > SHOW PROCESSLIST and the only process that came up was the SHOW PROCESSLIST process...so I don't think there are any queries hanging, but tbh I don't know.

Anyone have any tips how I might go about debugging this issue? This is on a GoDaddy VDS (CentOS) system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into the slow queries log to catch the query slowing down the box. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'll be taking this step immediately.

Question: Since no queries came up in SHOW PROCESSLIST I'm not positive that there are slow queries (will find out soon enough). Is the mysql process upticking in time as I described necessarily a problem? For all I know this could be expected.

Comment: D: Sorry for the late response, was waiting for items to show up in the log.

There is nothing substantial in the slow queries log...a query that searched a non-indexed column showed up, but this is in a process that only runs once a night and took 30s to run. I've set the slow_query_time to 1s, so I'm pretty confident issues aren't up this alley.

Meanwhile, our server locked up again two nights ago and I THINK it's still because of mysqld. When I run ps -ef now I see everything else is at time 00:00:00 except mysql which is at 00:04:27.

Any other thoughts on what I might look for?